# Use Rename collection in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, find, rename

I have a problem. I renamed my collection responses into old. It works really well but now I need to retrieve my data and my impediment is that I only used the model to retrieve my data from a collection. But now I need to retrieve my data from my renamed collection but I have no model and schema. I tried to create a schema and a model but it didn't work. It returns no elements.

Here is a part of the code :

```
app.get("/Play", function(req, res) {
  var urlTempBox = 'http://localhost:3000/Play';

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  request(urlTempBox, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      throw (error);
    } else {
      var jobj = JSON.parse(response.body);
      persistRS(jobj);

      setTimeout(function() {
        ResponseDatabase.find()
          .populate('unitCode')
          .exec(function(err, finalData) {
          if (err) throw (err);
          mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({
            name: 'old'
          })
            .next(function(err, collinfo) {
            if (err) throw (err);
            if (collinfo) {
              console.log('lookinOld');
              OldResponseDatabase.find()
                .populate('unitCode')
                .exec(function(err, oldData) {
                if (err) throw (err);
                console.log('itsOld');
                console.log(oldData);
                res.send(finalData);
              });
            } else {
              console.log('fk');
              res.send(finalData);
            }
          })
        })
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
```

Here is the part where it doesn't work: `console.log(oldData)` returns nothing. And I know that my data is in the database when I try to retrieve them.

```
if (collinfo) {
  console.log('lookinOld');
  OldResponseDatabase.find()
    .populate('unitCode')
    .exec(function(err, oldData) {
      if (err) throw (err);
      console.log('itsOld');
      console.log(oldData);
      res.send(finalData);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to do maybe it will be usefull for someone

You just need in your schema to precise the name of your collection like this 
( collection : 'old' )

```
var nameSchemaOldRS = new mongoose.Schema({
  MainClass: String,
  BookingClass: String,
  carID: String,
  unitCode:{type: String, ref: 'Map' ,required: [true,'No post id found']},
  Deck:Number,
  Orientation:String,
  Position:String, 
  }, {
  versionKey: false,
  collection : 'old' 
},);
```